# How can I avoid this piece of code remove my terms if there are no new terms found

Tags: term-store

I have a sharepoint 2010 environment with some custom solutions. Now I try to understand this piece of custom code. Can someone tell me whats happening. I would like to change this code, it needs to remove the terms only if the current terms are not empty. The reason why I would this is, sometimes these terms are filled, but sometimes they are empty after. I don't want to remove the terms if there is no new term for in place.

```
// check if these terms are equal
            var termComparer = new TermComparer();

            // original terms
            var removedTerms = originalTerms.Except(actualTerms, termComparer);

            // current terms
            var addedTerms = actualTerms.Except(originalTerms, termComparer);

            // Remove deleted terms
            foreach (var term in removedTerms)
            {
                DiagnosticsService.LogMessage("Removing term " + term.Labels.First().Value, 0, DiagnosticsCategory.Jobs);

                profile[profileFieldName].RemoveTaxonomyTerm(term);
            }

            // check object value 
            if (addedTerms != null)
            {
                // Remove added terms
                foreach (var term in addedTerms)
                {
                    if (term != null)
                    {
                        profile[profileFieldName].AddTaxonomyTerm(term);
                    }
                }
            }

            profile.Commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
// Remove deleted terms if addedTerms is not null and has at least on item in the collection

if(addedTerms != null && addedTerms.Count > 0){ // addedTerms.Count may be incorrect property based on that I have no knowledge of the type of addedTerms...
    // Remove original terms
    foreach (var term in removedTerms)
    {
        DiagnosticsService.LogMessage("Removing term " + term.Labels.First().Value, 0, DiagnosticsCategory.Jobs);

         profile[profileFieldName].RemoveTaxonomyTerm(term);
    }

    // Add current terms
    foreach (var term in addedTerms)
    {
          if (term != null)
          {
              profile[profileFieldName].AddTaxonomyTerm(term);
          }
    }
}
```